# multiple onclick's in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a an HTML page with a list of 20 topics on it. I would like it so that when you click on one of those topics, 2 or 3 articles with links pop up underneath it.

I'm trying `onclick` but it means writing lots of code as you have to declare all the `div` styles for each of my topics.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

im currently writing this 20 times, and declaring 60 div styles:

```
<div class = "mousehand"
id = "show_first"
onclick ="this.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('show_second').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display='inline';
"> show text </div>

<div class = "mousehand"
id = "show_second"
onclick ="this.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('show_first').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('dropdown').style.display='none';
"> hide text </div>


<div id ="dropdown"> this is the text to be shown</div>
```

Comment: I think onclick is fine. Use jQuery (or another similar framework) in your JavaScript code, it's pretty simple and effective for such things.

Comment: Are you using a web application language to generate HTML? Like ASP.NET or PHP?

Comment: hey. no, on this page its just html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with some Javascript. Add a `ul` within the `li`:

```
<li>Title
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

Set the inner `ul`'s display to `none` using CSS. Then using Javascript, make a function that changes the display property of the inner `ul` to `block`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, jQuery can make this very straightforward, but your major code saving is going to come from taking advantage of event bubbling.  You can do this is you structure your HTML something like this:

```
<div id="topics">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="show">
            show text 1
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            hide text 1
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            this is the text to be shown 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="show">
            show text 2
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            hide text 2
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            this is the text to be shown 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now instead of attaching an `onclick` handler to each end every `div`, attach it to the parent element.  To do this with jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){                        //Do this when the page loads
    $('#topics').bind('click', function(event) {  //Find the element with ID 'topics' and attach a click handler
        var t = $(event.target);                  //event.target is the element that was actually clicked, $() gets the jQuery version of it
        if(t.hasClass('show')) {                  //If it is a 'show' element...
            t.siblings('.hide').show();           //...show the other two elements...
            t.siblings('.text').show();
            t.hide();                             //...and hide the clicked element
        }
        if(t.hasClass('hide')) {                  //If it is a 'hide' element...
            t.siblings('.show').show();           //...show the 'show' element...
            t.siblings('.text').hide();           //...and hide the other two
            t.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And that's it!  [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/JJTnT/).